# Create links from node border to node border, not center to center

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Whereas I see most of the examples on internet has links from one node border to other node border, in my case (I am not sure what different I did) it is from center to center. Which doesn't look good to me.

How can I draw link from one node border to other (not from center to center)?

```
link.enter()
  .insert('line')
  .attr('class', 'link')
  .attr('marker-mid', 'url(#mid)')
  .attr('x1', function(d) {
    return d.source.x;
  })
  .attr('y1', function(d) {
    return d.source.y;
  })
  .attr('x2', function(d) {
    return d.target.x;
  })
  .attr('y2', function(d) {
    return d.target.y;
  })
  .style('stroke', colors.links)
  .style('opacity', function(d) {
    return d.target.module ? 0.2 : 0.3
  })
```

My plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/haPmq3LXpyJgCu1u9aCU?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the angle between the two nodes with...

```
Math.atan2(d.target.y - d.source.y, d.target.x - d.source.x)
```

... and then use `Math.sin()` and `Math.cos()` for changing the positions:

```
link.attr('x1', function(d) {
        return d.source.x + (Math.cos(Math.atan2(d.target.y - d.source.y, d.target.x - d.source.x)) * 24);
    })
    .attr('y1', function(d) {
        return d.source.y + (Math.sin(Math.atan2(d.target.y - d.source.y, d.target.x - d.source.x)) * 24);
    })
    .attr('x2', function(d) {
        return d.target.x - (Math.cos(Math.atan2(d.target.y - d.source.y, d.target.x - d.source.x)) * 24);
    })
    .attr('y2', function(d) {
        return d.target.y - (Math.sin(Math.atan2(d.target.y - d.source.y, d.target.x - d.source.x)) * 24);
    });
```

Here, the magic number `24` is the radius of those nodes.

That's just to give you the basic idea, you can improve that code in several ways. For instance, to avoid calculating the (same) angle 4 times at each tick, you can use a local variable or a datum.

Here is the updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/rXCaKjRTTBzrItFmbVYt?p=preview. For better showing that the links stop at the borders of the nodes I'm increasing the links' width and the nodes' opacity.

Comment: PS: when I first read the question I thought that this would be certainly a dupe... however, apparently it's not (there is one similar Q/A but for `<path>` elements, not `<line>` elements).

Comment: @unknown by the way, you didn't do anything wrong: most examples online go from centre to centre... what happens is that they paint the circle **on top** of the lines, so, you can't tell the difference.

Comment: Thats what I was wondering why its not happening in my case.. however your 2nd clue is also very useful.