# D3.js Force links to rectangle node border

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have been trying to experiment with D3.js I am unable to making the links in a graph point to the node borders instead of the node centers.

I have been using the following jsfiddle to test it, but I am still not able to do it...

http://jsfiddle.net/srikanthp0548/Lnc9a57r/6/

Here is my tick code:

```
  link.attr('x1', function(d) {
      return d.source.x + (Math.cos(Math.atan2(d.target.y - d.source.y, d.target.x - d.source.x)) * 24);
    })
    .attr('y1', function(d) {
      return d.source.y + (Math.sin(Math.atan2(d.target.y - d.source.y, d.target.x - d.source.x)) * 24);
    })
    .attr('x2', function(d) {
      return d.target.x - (Math.cos(Math.atan2(d.target.y - d.source.y, d.target.x - d.source.x)) * 24);
    })
    .attr('y2', function(d) {
      return d.target.y - (Math.sin(Math.atan2(d.target.y - d.source.y, d.target.x - d.source.x)) * 24);
    });
```

I suppose that I have to update something in the tick() function to return different values:

I am using rectangle nodes instead of circles. Links are starting at the center of rectangle.

I picked up the answer from this [Create links from node border to node border, not center to center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49794102/create-links-from-node-border-to-node-border-not-center-to-center)

How can I draw link from one node border to other (not from center to center)? Any help would be much apperciated

Comment: @gerardo can you please help here

Answer (score 0):

In the `tick()` function, you are setting x1, y1, x2, y2 attributes on a SVG polyline element that does not support these attributes. Use the SVG `line` element instead when you create your links and they will be displayed correctly.

Comment: Yes, I updated it to the 'line' http://jsfiddle.net/srikanthp0548/Lnc9a57r/ still no luck.